How can I select a blank field at SAP using vscode and Python?
How can I select a field in this SAP GUI screen? Like the one in red, next to Sales Organization.

I tried using some pyautogui code but it didn't work, such as pyautogui.click().
Also, how can I run the code while I use other windows at the desktop?
My code:
`#Open SAP LOGON
subprocess.check_call(['C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\\sapshcut.exe', '-system=LAP'])
time.sleep(10)
SapGuiAuto = win32com.client.GetObject('SAPGUI')
application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
connection = application.Children(0)
session = connection.Children(0)

pyautogui.typewrite('Y_LAD_65000687')
pyautogui.press('enter')`


I'm trying to select using pyautogui, but it doesn't select the field like I want to.

Please update your question to clarify what exactly means "select a field". I guess you want to type a value in the screen field "Sales organization" (which is not the same as "select a field").
